# Lógica de programación en scratch

Tags: programación-funcional, lógica

Hola compañeros programadores, estoy practicando mi lógica de programación con Scratch, pero me he topado con un ejerció un poco complicado para y mi. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado la lógica para avanzar y extraer el mineral, pero me pide hacerlo con máximo 16 comandos. Si podrían ayudarme, se los agradezco

Comment: yo creo que podrías comprobar si hay espacio adelante y si no girar a la derecha, así recorrerías todo el laberinto y extraerías todo el mineral

Comment: Creo que se formaría un ciclo infinito después de extraer el mineral de la fila donde esta.

Comment: Cuál es el problema exacto que estás teniendo?

Comment: completar el desafio

Comment: ¿Lograste resolverlo? Justamente estoy revisando lo mismo y no he podido encontrar la solución.